# Keep alive applet object even page is reloaded?

Tags: java, jquery, applet

I in position to hold my applet object in my HTML page even page is refreshed or redirected to any other page, Because of the object will use to get the value that are loaded initially in applet, so i have tried to store the object in jQuery session variable, but i couldn't do this, so please any one help me to save the object in a jQuery session variable or please suggest me the way reach my requirement..

Comment: By "applet", do you actually mean a Java (not Javascript!) applet embedded in the page, or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mo, it is not possible, since it goes against how an applet is supposed to operate.  Store the relevant data in cookies and have the applet check for the cookies first.